# C# datetime parse meaning of percentage symbol(%)

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string iString = "12/3/2017 03:24:02 PM";
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "%M/%d/yyyy %h:%m:%s tt",null);
    Console.WriteLine (oDate);
  }
}
```

In the above code, parsing format includes multiple % symbols. What do they mean? Are they supposed to take care of both single/double digit months/dates etc?

Comment: This is covered by the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers). In this case, the use of `%` is optional since the string is more than one character, and it has no particular effect. The author may have preferred it for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers

> A custom date and time format string consists of two or more
> characters. Date and time formatting methods interpret any
> single-character string as a standard date and time format string. If
> they do not recognize the character as a valid format specifier, they
> throw a FormatException. For example, a format string that consists
> only of the specifier "h" is interpreted as a standard date and time
> format string. However, in this particular case, an exception is
> thrown because there is no "h" standard date and timeformat specifier.
>
> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only
> specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g",
> "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format
> specifier by itself), include a space before or after the specifier,
> or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom
> date and time specifier.
>
> For example, "%h" is interpreted as a custom date and time format
> string that displays the hour represented by the current date and time
> value. You can also use the " h" or "h " format string, although this
> includes a space in the result string along with the hour. The
> following example illustrates these three format strings.

```
DateTime dat1 = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 45, 0);

Console.WriteLine("'{0:%h}'", dat1);
Console.WriteLine("'{0: h}'", dat1);
Console.WriteLine("'{0:h }'", dat1);
// The example displays the following output:
//       '1'
//       ' 1'
//       '1 '
```